# How to set session id or create custom field into ApplicationInsights from FunctionApp

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, telemetry

Function app is as below:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage request, ILogger log)
    {
     log.LogInformation("Information", infoOBject);
    }
```

local.json file has applicationInstrument key.

How to add additional field and set "Session_Id" for "Request" entry in application insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to this using some custom logging from Application Insights

First, install the Nuget package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights -Version 2.7.2
```

Then change your above code like below

```
public static class Function1
    {
        private static TelemetryClient GetTelemetryClient()
        {
            var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
            telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = "<your actual insight instrumentkey>";
            telemetryClient.Context.Session.Id = "124556";
            //update 1-Custom properties- Start
            telemetry.Context.Properties["tags"] = "PROD";
            telemetry.Context.Properties["userCorelateId"]="1234"; 
            //update 1-Custom properties- Ends                
            return telemetryClient;
            }       


        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
        {
            var appInsights = GetTelemetryClient();           
            appInsights.TrackRequest(req.RequestUri.ToString(), DateTime.Now, Stopwatch.StartNew().Elapsed, "200", true);
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "message");

        }


    }
```

Finally in the appinsights

[image]

### Update 1

You can also add your own additional properties within the request.

```
E.g,
telemetry.Context.Properties["tags"] = "PROD";
```

This will add the properties under the `customDimension` properties

[image]

You can also [refer here](https://cmatskas.com/azure-functions-custom-logging-with-appinsights/)

Comment: this log two request. One request is already created by default. May be because of configured, instrumentKey. By doing above stuff, it creates another request. Any solution for, only one "request" and having sessionId ?

Comment: also, can we add additional column to "Request"  as similar to session_id. Like, userCorelateId column ?

Comment: @user3711357 what do you mean by two requests here? I could see an only single request, which is created by `appInsights.TrackRequest`

Comment: @user3711357 I've updated my answer by using adding the custom properties. Hope this helps

Comment: Is there need to call appInsights.Flush() or its not require ?

Comment: It based on the situation.I've provided the detailed answer to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099180/is-there-memory-impact-or-performance-cause-without-telemetryclient-flush)