# Is there memory impact or performance cause without TelemetryClient.Flush()

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, telemetry

Using telemetry client to log custom event log as follow:

```
  var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
  telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = "<your actual insight instrumentkey>";    
  telemetryClient.TrackRequest(req.RequestUri.ToString(), DateTime.Now, Stopwatch.StartNew().Elapsed, "200", true);
```

My question is: do we need to flush the client using `telemetryClient.Flush()` or is it not required?

Even when not flushing it also works and we are able to see the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, you don't need to call `flush()` if you not **aware of the point in which the application is shut down**. The `flush` is really pushing all the data into app insights (background).

But let say if you know the point in which the application is **shut down** then you can call the `flush` manually to make sure all the data sent properly(without keeping anything in the buffer)

Typically if you call the `flush` it will send the data immediately without keeping in the buffer

[Refer this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954418/flush-in-azure-app-insights)

Comment: thanks for the comment and share the attached link too.